# Where does Flex 4 states sit with components and frameworks?

Tags: flex4, components, states, mate

Basically each of them tries to build smaller manageable parts of an application, but now I'm getting a little confused. I've seen the Mate Framework which claims to be an eventbased framework, but somehow the new States feels like it's overlapping. Can someone more enlightened than me bring some light on the subject, please!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

States and events are 2 things totally different.

States is something you use inside a component. It represents the different state a component can have depending of some variables. For example, a login box could have a signup state and a signin state.

Events are used to communicate between components in a decoupled way.

At the end, you use both in an application.